# A basic application of Mackey theory

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

This is Exercise 32.5 from the chapter on [Mackey theory](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-8024-2_32) in the textbook [Lie groups by D. Bump](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4614-8024-2). Any suggestions and comments would be appreciated. Thanks!

Let $G=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & x & z \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}:x,y,z,\in\Bbb F_q\right\}$. Let $Z=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & z \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}:z\in \Bbb F_q\right\}$ and $A=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & z \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}:y,z\in \Bbb F_q\right\}$. Note that $Z$ is in the center of $G$ and $A$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$ but it contains non central elements. (So, $G\geq A\gneq Z$.) Let $\chi$ and $\psi$ be two linear characters of $A$. Assume that $\chi$ and $\psi$ have nontrivial restrictions to $Z$. Let $\chi^G$ and $\psi^G$ be the induced representations. Use Mackey theory to prove that

$$\dim\operatorname{Hom}_G(\chi^G,\psi^G)=  \begin{cases} 
   1 & \text{if $\chi,\psi$ have the same restriction to Z}  \\
   0       & \text{otherwise.}
  \end{cases}
$$

---

**Attempt.** I think we may use the following theorem.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H_1,H_2$ be subgroups of $G$. Let $(\pi_1, V_1)$ and $(\pi_2,V_2)$ be representations of $H_1$ and $H_2$, respectively. For any $\gamma$, we define $H_\gamma=H_2\cap \gamma H_1\gamma^{-1}$ and define two representations $(\pi_1^\gamma, V_1)$ and $(\pi_2^\gamma, V_2)$ of $H_\gamma$ as follows. The representation  $\pi_2^\gamma$ is just the restriction of $\pi_2$ to $H_\gamma$. On the other hand, we define $\pi_1^\gamma(h)=\pi_1(\gamma^{-1}h\gamma)$ for $h\in H_\gamma$.

**Theorem 32.2.**
Let $\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\dots,\gamma_n\}$ be a complete set of representatives of the double cosets in $H_2\setminus G / H_1$. Then we have
$$\dim\operatorname{Hom}_G(V_1^G,V_2^G)=\sum_{i=1}^n\dim\operatorname{Hom}_{H_{\gamma_i}}(\pi_1^{\gamma_i},\pi_2^{\gamma_i}).$$

From here, if $H_1=H_2=A$ then I think we need to find a complete set of representatives of the double cosets in $H_2\backslash G / H_1.$

Comment: What is Mackey theory and how is it related to this?

Comment: Mackey theory is exactly the study of representation-theoretic induction–restriction, as occurs here by Frobenius reciprocity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is $A$ an Abelian subgroup, but also it is a *normal* Abelian subgroup, since it contains $Z$, which in turn contains the commutator subgroup of $G$.  (In fact, $G$ is often presented in the exact sequence $1 \to Z \to G \to \mathbb F_q^2 \to 1$ *via* $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & z \\ & 1 & y \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto (x, y)$, with respect to which the commutator becomes a symplectic pairing on $\mathbb F_q^2 \times \mathbb F_q^2 \to Z \cong \mathbb F_q$.)

Thus, $A\backslash G/A$ is just $G/A$, which is $\mathbb F_q$ *via* $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & z \\ & 1 & y \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto x$.

It thus suffices to determine for which $x \in \mathbb F_q$ we have that, in your notation, $\chi^{\gamma_x^+}$ intertwines over $H_{\gamma_x} = A$ with $\psi^{\gamma_x^+}$—that is to say, for which $x$ they are equal—where $\gamma_x^+ = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ & 1 \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix}$.  Note that $\left[\gamma_x^+, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ & 1 & y \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix}\right]$ equals $\begin{pmatrix} 1 && x y \\ & 1 \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix}$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb F_q$.  If we let $x_0$ be the unique element of $\mathbb F_q$ such that $\psi\chi^{-1}$ (which is trivial on $Z$) equals
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 1 && z \\ & 1 & y \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \chi\begin{pmatrix} 1 && x_0 y \\ & 1 \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix} = \psi\begin{pmatrix} 1 && x_0 y \\ & 1 \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
(which exists because any character of $\mathbb F_q \cong A/Z$ can be obtained from any non-degenerate character of $\mathbb F_q \cong Z$ by scaling by an appropriate element of $\mathbb F_q)$, then $\chi^{\gamma_x^+}$ equals $\psi^{\gamma_x^+}$ if and only if $x$ equals $x_0$ (unless I've made a sign error, and it should be $x = -x_0$).  (The key point is that $A$ is the pullback to $G$ of a Lagrangian subspace of $\mathbb F_q^2$, i.e., a maximal subspace on which the symplectic pairing is trivial.)

Thus, in your Mackey-theoretic computation of the intertwining number, only $x = x_0$ contributes, giving $\dim \operatorname{Hom}_G(\chi^G, \psi^G) = \dim \operatorname{Hom}_A(\chi^{\gamma_{x_0}^+}, \psi^{\gamma_{x_0}^+}) = 1$.

Comment: @ErginSüer, sorry, you are [right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410403/a-basic-application-of-mackey-theory/4410479#comment9241389_4410479); only one double coset contributes, but it need not be the identity coset.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: What do we mean by $\chi^{-1}$ when we define $\psi\chi^{-1}$? Also, I'm not so familiar with the terminology of symplectic pairing. It would be great if you could explain it a little bit. Thanks!

Comment: $\psi$ and $\chi$ are maps $A \to \mathbb C^\times$, and $\psi\chi^{-1}$ is the map $z \mapsto \psi(z)\chi(z)^{-1}$.  A [symplectic pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space) on $\mathbb F_p^2$ is a map $\mathbb F_p^2 \times \mathbb F_p^2 \to \mathbb F_p$, which I'll denote by $(x, y) \mapsto \langle x, y\rangle$, that is bilinear (i.e., linear in each variable) and alternating, in the sense that $\langle x, x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$ (equivalently, since $p \ne 2$, in the sense that $\langle x, y\rangle = -\langle y, x\rangle$ for all $x$, $y$).